# How can I get the profile image of an Instagram user?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have some codes that I found for profile picture (which works very well) However, how can I do it for the post picture. (Like: https://www.instagram.com/p/CAnkEFFnlC2/)

```js
function getPhoto(a) {

  // validation for instagram usernames
  var regex = new RegExp(/^(?!.*\.\.)(?!.*\.$)[^\W][\w.]{0,29}$/);
  var validation = regex.test(a);

  if (validation) {
    $.get("https://www.instagram.com/" + a + "/?__a=1")
      .done(function(data) {

        // getting the url
        var photoURL = data["graphql"]["user"]["profile_pic_url_hd"];

        // update img element
        $("#photoReturn").attr("src", photoURL)
      })
      .fail(function() {
        // code for 404 error 
        console.log('Username was not found!')
      })
  } else {
    console.log('The username is invalid!')
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="" id="photoReturn">
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="usernameInput">
<button onclick="getPhoto($('#usernameInput').val().trim())">Get profile photo</button>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: any help? because the problem still goes on

Comment: This issue still continue

Answer (score 1):

Its really simple, add  /media?size=l at the end of your url.

Ex: https://www.instagram.com/p/CAnkEFFnlC2/media?size=l
(Parameters)   l,m,s,t stands for large,medium,small and thumbnail size.